# How to add multiple date in a table in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, date

I am trying to show a specific day of each month in a table in a react component. I have tried the codes below and it did not work. tried to search over the internet but couldn't get enough useful advices. Please help.

```
 const calculate = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
    const d= new Date;
    const n = d. getFullYear()+'-'+(d. getMonth()+1)+'-'+d. getDate();
    setDate(n);
    const m = (d. getFullYear()+'-'+d. getMonth()+1+'-'+d. getDate())+30;
    setM(m);
};

 return (
    <div>
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Deposit Amount</th>
                  <th>Interest</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Total Interest</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>{principal}</td>
                  <td>{total}</td>
                  <td>{date}</td>
                  <td>{result}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>{principal}</td>
                  <td>{total}</td>
                  <td>{date1}</td>
                  <td>{result1}</td>
                </tr>
<tr>
    

              <td>2</td>
                  <td>{principal}</td>
                  <td>{total}</td>
                  <td>{date2}</td>
                  <td>{result2}</td>
                </tr>
</thead>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to show the formatted date in 30 days intervals

Try below

```js
const App = () => {

  const getDateAfter = (days) => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + days);
    return `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth() + 1}-${d.getDate()}`;
  };

  let data = [
     { principal: "********", total: "********", result: "********" },
     { principal: "********", total: "********", result: "********" },
     { principal: "********", total: "********", result: "********" },
     { principal: "********", total: "********", result: "********" },
     { principal: "********", total: "********", result: "********" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Deposit Amount</th>
          <th>Interest</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Total Interest</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map(({ principal, total, result }, index) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{index + 1}</td>
            <td>{principal}</td>
            <td>{total}</td>
            <td>{getDateAfter(30 * index)}</td>
            <td>{result}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: @Shahnawaz Ayon, check this out!!